# Parsing CSVs for bulk database insertions

Tags: csv, go, mongodb

I'm writing this as (eventually) part of a larger program. This will serve as the bulk data insertion from .csv files we parse.

I'm primarily looking for parts that are

1. breaking Go's formatting, styling, etc. rules
2. redundant and/or dangerous

Right now the code works and all 4 million rows of the .csv file were properly inserted into the database.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

// Set up primarily for ease of changing hosts if necessary
const (
    MongoDBHost = "127.0.0.1:27017"
)

// TODO: Check if channel's buffer size is necessary
// ctr increments for each row of the csv inserted (allows us to keep track)
var (
    channel = make(chan []string, 4000000)
    ctr     int
)

// Person is the model struct for inserting into a mongodb
// Each member corresponds with a field in the VRDB, sans the last member
// The last member is for updating entries
// Parsing the csv files returns a []string per row
type Person struct {
    StateVoterId          string
    CountyVoterId         string
    Title                 string
    FName                 string
    MName                 string
    LName                 string
    NameSuffix            string
    Birthdate             string
    Gender                string
    RegStNum              string
    RegStFrac             string
    RegStName             string
    RegStType             string
    RegUnitType           string
    RegStPreDirection     string
    RegStPostDirection    string
    RegUnitNum            string
    RegCity               string
    RegState              string
    RegZipCode            string
    CountyCode            string
    PrecinctCode          string
    PrecinctPart          string
    LegislativeDistrict   string
    CongressionalDistrict string
    Mail1                 string
    Mail2                 string
    Mail3                 string
    Mail4                 string
    MailCity              string
    MailZip               string
    MailState             string
    MailCountry           string
    RegistrationDate      string
    AbsenteeType          string
    StatusCode            string
    LastVoted             string
    Updated               time.Time
}

func main() {
    runtime.GOMAXPROCS(4) // Supposedly makes things faster
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    // Start our mongodb session
    mongoSession, err := mgo.Dial(MongoDBHost)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("CreateSession: %s\n", err)
    }
    mongoSession.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    // Start loading and parsing our .csv file
    // testing file: csv.csv
    // current file: big-huge-csv-file.csv
    csvfile, err := os.Open("../data/big-huge-csv-file.csv")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    defer csvfile.Close()

    reader := csv.NewReader(csvfile)

    reader.Comma = '\t'             // It's a tab-delimited file
    reader.LazyQuotes = true        // Some fields are like \t"F" ST.\t
    reader.FieldsPerRecord = 0      // -1 is variable #, 0 is [0]th line's #
    reader.TrimLeadingSpace = false // Keep the fields' whitespace how it is

Loop:
    for {
        // Add another goroutine to our wait group
        wg.Add(1)
        // Increment our counter per row
        ctr++
        data, err := reader.Read()

        switch err {
        case io.EOF:
            fmt.Println("Finished reading CSV (hit EOF)")
            break Loop
        case nil:
            channel <- data
            go InsertPerson(channel, mongoSession, &wg, ctr)
        // Handles all cases where err != EOF || err != nil
        default:
            fmt.Printf("Error while reading %s: %s\n", csvfile, err)
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        wg.Wait()
    }
    fmt.Println("Done")
}

func InsertPerson(c chan []string, mongoSession *mgo.Session, wg *sync.WaitGroup, ctr int) {
    // Decrement wg counter when func finishes
    defer wg.Done()

    // Shows us our progress in increments of 5,000
    if ctr%5000 == 0 {
        fmt.Println(ctr)
    }

    // Receive from our channel
    row := <-c

    // Setting up our db connections
    sessionCopy := mongoSession.Copy()
    defer sessionCopy.Close()

    // TODO: Change from "test" to prod db
    collection := mongoSession.DB("test").C("People")
    index := mgo.Index{
        Key:        []string{"StateVoterId"},
        Unique:     true,
        DropDups:   true,
        Background: true,
        Sparse:     true,
        Name:       "SoS Voter IDs",
    }

    ensureIndexErr := collection.EnsureIndex(index)
    if ensureIndexErr != nil {
        log.Fatal(ensureIndexErr)
    }

    // Insert people into mongodb
    // TODO: Find a less ugly way to do this
    // According to #go-nuts the only other way uses reflection, and I'd
    // rather not use reflection if I don't have to
    insertErr := collection.Insert(Person{row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[19], row[20], row[21], row[22], row[23], row[24], row[25], row[26], row[27], row[28], row[29], row[30], row[31], row[32], row[33], row[34], row[35], row[36], time.Now()})

    // We refuse to gracefully fail as any incorrect inserts need to be
    // rectified manually to ensure our data is correct
    if insertErr != nil {
        log.Printf("InsertPerson : ERROR : %s\n", insertErr)
        log.Fatal(insertErr)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have lots of experience with **Go**, but here are some suggestions:

1. Avoid global var

First, avoid global var as much as you can: `channel` and `ctr` could be declared in the `main()` function

2. Wrong use of channel and goroutines

this line create a buffered channel containing all the rows

```
channel = make(chan []string, 4000000)
```

and for each row, you create a goroutine to make an insert. This is highly inneficient and make the code less easy to understand. I guess that you wanted to read the file and insert document in parallel to speed up the process. But this is definitely premature optimisation here, as you don't know wich part of the code is the bottleneck...

3. Performance

Didn't even tried to run the provided code, I don't get how it achieve to finish: 
when a `Person`is inserted, the whole index is rebuild (ie 4000000 times ! ). This is very expensive and totally useless. 
If the collection is empty at the beginning, just create the index when all records have been inserted, this will speed up the insertion.

4. Some other ideas:

   - Make sure that the collection is empty before importing with `collection.DropCollection()` ?
   - Some field from the CSV could be stored as [int](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) to reduce their size in database
   - use `bulk.Unordered()` to speed up the insert, but insertion errors will be ignored...
   - Avoid hard coded path, use flag to provide arguments like file or database

So the code could be :

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "time"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)

// Set up primarily for ease of changing hosts if necessary
const (
    MongoDBHost = "127.0.0.1:27017"
)

// Person is the model struct for inserting into a mongodb
// Each member corresponds with a field in the VRDB, sans the last member
// The last member is for updating entries
// Parsing the csv files returns a []string per row
type Person struct {
    StateVoterId          string
    CountyVoterId         string
    Title                 string
    FName                 string
    MName                 string
    LName                 string
    NameSuffix            string
    Birthdate             string
    Gender                string
    RegStNum              string
    RegStFrac             string
    RegStName             string
    RegStType             string
    RegUnitType           string
    RegStPreDirection     string
    RegStPostDirection    string
    RegUnitNum            string
    RegCity               string
    RegState              string
    RegZipCode            string
    CountyCode            string
    PrecinctCode          string
    PrecinctPart          string
    LegislativeDistrict   string
    CongressionalDistrict string
    Mail1                 string
    Mail2                 string
    Mail3                 string
    Mail4                 string
    MailCity              string
    MailZip               string
    MailState             string
    MailCountry           string
    RegistrationDate      string
    AbsenteeType          string
    StatusCode            string
    LastVoted             string
    Updated               time.Time
}

func main() {
    // Start our mongodb session
    mongoSession, err := mgo.Dial(MongoDBHost)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("CreateSession: %s\n", err.Error())
    }
    defer mongoSession.Close()
    mongoSession.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
    collection := mongoSession.DB("test").C("People")
    // Start loading and parsing our .csv file
    csvfile, err := os.Open("./file.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer csvfile.Close()
    reader := csv.NewReader(csvfile)

    reader.Comma = '\t'             // It's a tab-delimited file
    reader.LazyQuotes = true        // Some fields are like \t"F" ST.\t
    reader.FieldsPerRecord = 0      // -1 is variable #, 0 is [0]th line's #
    reader.TrimLeadingSpace = false // Keep the fields' whitespace how it is
    bulk := collection.Bulk()
    count := 0
    for {
        row, err := reader.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            _, err = bulk.Run()
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("bulk insert failed: %s\n", err.Error())
            }
            break
        }
        bulk.Insert(Person{row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4], row[5], row[6], row[7], row[8], row[9], row[10], row[11], row[12], row[13], row[14], row[15], row[16], row[17], row[18], row[19], row[20], row[21], row[22], row[23], row[24], row[25], row[26], row[27], row[28], row[29], row[30], row[31], row[32], row[33], row[34], row[35], row[36], time.Now()})
        count++
        if count%1000 == 0 {
            _, err = bulk.Run()
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("bulk insert failed: %s\n", err.Error())
            }
            // reset the bulk
            bulk = collection.Bulk()
            fmt.Println(count)
        }
    }
    // create the index once all documents have been inserted
    index := mgo.Index{
        Key:        []string{"StateVoterId"},
        Unique:     true,
        DropDups:   true,
        Background: true,
        Sparse:     true,
        Name:       "SoS Voter IDs",
    }
    err = collection.EnsureIndex(index)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Done")
}
```

or simply use

```
mongoimport --db test --collection People --type csv --headerline --file ../data/big-huge-csv-file.csv
```

([mongoimport](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) is a tool provided by MongoDB to import data from different source, and is written in **Go**)